# Make only the centered image clickable

Tags: css

So I got this image inside a link, I managed to center the image but the problem is the link taking the entire container, on the right and left of the image you can click, That's not what I want! I want only the image to be clickable.

I'm stuck on this please help.

https://jsfiddle.net/2ycyzmw5/

```css
.salo img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="salo">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it inside a `div`.  Give `.salo img` `display: inline-block;` and then give the `.wrapper` `text-align: center`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmulder5/2ycyzmw5/4/)

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.salo img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="salo">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The `display: inline-block` on the `img` is not needed

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I appreciate the help. Have a nice day sir.

Answer (score 5):

Just do like this, no extra wrapper needed.

```css
.salo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="salo">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
</a>
```

Comment: Clean and simple, the way I do! +1

Answer (score 1):

Two ways, having a container div with `text-align:center`

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/skef55oe/1/)

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.salo {
  display: inline-block;
}
.salo img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="salo">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
  </a>
</div>
```

Or without the need for extra markup, making use of positioning it, with `left:50%` and `transofrm:translateX(-50%)`, this way we shift *from* the left by **`50%`** of the viewport width, and shift it backward by **`50%`** of the `a` width.

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/2ycyzmw5/5/)

```css
.salo {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-block;
}
.salo img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="salo">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
</a>
```

---

A third way is making use of `calc()` function, you can use this of you know the exact width of the image, just like this:

[**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/2ycyzmw5/7/)

```css
.salo {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  display: inline-block;
}
.salo img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="salo">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
</a>
```